# SED command error in removing column name

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to add the value of a count from a sql query to a variable. but I get the below error with the sed command.

Code:

```
DISTINCT_C=`mysqlsh --sql IP -u user-ppassword  -D schema-e"SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT TRIM(ACCOUNT_BALANCES_APPEAL_ID)) from RAO_ACCOUNT_BALANCES_APPEAL WHERE UPDATED_ON >= TIMESTAMP('$LAST_TIMESTAMP')"`
DCOUNT=`echo "$DISTINCT_C" | sed 's/ //2'`
echo $DCOUNT
```

Error:

> COUNT( DISTINCTTRIM(ACCOUNT_BALANCES_APPEAL_ID)) 0
>   sed: can't read DISTINCTTRIM(ACCOUNT_BALANCES_APPEAL_ID)): No such file or directory
>   sed: can't read 0: No such file or directory

any help is appreciated.

Comment: FYI, please use the `$()` syntax to run commands, and not the quote \` anymore.  It caused confusion in your question.  To help more, please add the result of this to the question:  `echo $DISTINCT`

Comment: hi Nic, 
COUNT( DISTINCTTRIM(ACCOUNT_BALANCES_APPEAL_ID)) 0
is the output of echo $DISTINCT

Comment: So you want the 0 (or other value that is displayed)?  Replace your sed with this: `awk '{print $3}'`.  This will give you the third item (separated by space).

Comment: the row count can be any number.. it could be more in 2,3 or 4 digits, would this still work/?

Comment: Yes, it separates on the space, no matter how long it is.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also as you spoke about awk,
can you tell me what this command does? I am confused with this one,
ROW_COUNT=`awk '/^Number of rows exported:/ {print $NF}' ${TABLE_NAME}_AF_${CURR_DATE}.rpt | xargs -n 1 printf "%d"` || 0

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer below (the check mark besides the answer).  Then post a new question with that.  Make sure you show the values of `$TABLE_NAME $CURR_DATE`.  Also a sample of the content of the `...rpt`.  Awk takes out text from the `.rpt` file and prints it as a decimal number (`xargs...printf`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk to print the last word (separated by spaces).  Here it will be the 0, or any other number.

Like this:

```
echo $DISTINCT | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

If $DISTINCT changes in the future, this will always print the last word, so no need to adjust the code to take into account for additional spaces.  As long as the value you want is the last word.